# How to correctly delete an allocated array (queue data structure)

Tags: c++, arrays, queue, delete-operator

I created a queue data structure using a struct and a dynamically allocated array, I don't understand what is the right way to free or delete it without any memory leaks.

I have tried using the following:

delete[] q->data;

delete[] &(q->data);

delete &(q->data);

```
#include "queue.h"

void initQueue(queue* q, unsigned int size)
{
    q->maxSize = size;
    q->size = 0;
    q->data = new unsigned int[size];
    q->front = 0;
    q->rear = 0;
}

void enqueue(queue* q, unsigned int newValue)
{
    if (q->size != q->maxSize)
    {
        q->data[q->rear] = newValue;
        q->size++;
        q->rear++;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Queue is full! you can clean it and initialize a new one" << std::endl;
    }
}

int dequeue(queue* q)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (q->size == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Queue is empty!" << std::endl;
        return EMPTY;
    }
    else
    {
        q->front++;
        q->size--;

        return q->data[q->front];
    }
}

void cleanQueue(queue* q)
{
    //the delete function
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `delete[] q->data;` accomplish what you need?

Comment: `new []` and `delete []` must go together. `new` without `[]` and `delete` without `[]` must go together. I suspect there are multiple posts at SO that address the issue.

Comment: Often in C++ we encapsulate resource management in a class and use constructors and destructors of the class to initialize or clean up the resource. By following that pattern you can eliminate the chances of a user of your queue from calling `initQueue()` but never calling `cleanQueue()`, which in your case could lead to a memory leak.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I thought it would lead to a memory leak.. can you confirm/deny this?

Comment: @Flametrav "_I thought it would lead to a memory leak_" Why would you _think_ that? How did you come to such conclusion? Do you have an output, of a tool, that confirms, that something leaves a memory leak, and you misinterpreted the place, where it happens?

Answer (score 0):

The technical right answer here is to delete q->data, as others have suggested. But...

> right way to free or delete it without any memory leaks

The right way in C++, unless you're doing some exotic with allocation, is not to do your own memory management. Write a class that allocates in the constructor, and deletes in the destructor, as Chris suggested, is a great way to learn about RAII and how it saves you from the mental burden of manually writing "delete" everywhere.

But the right right way, if someone was paying me? I'd skip all that and use a vector.

```
#include <vector>

class MyQueue {
public:
    MyQueue(unsigned int size) : data(size) { }
    void enqueue(unsigned int value) { /* whatever... */ }
    int dequeue() { /* whatever... */ }
private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> data;
};
```

When this class goes out of scope or gets deleted, the vector will automatically be cleaned up. You don't even need to free or delete anything.